# Deleting records from a database

Tags: database-design

I would like to know about the standard practice of deleting records from a database.

As an example, a user has deleted a record but we still want to keep a log of the record deleted and from which user, in order to retrieve it if there was an error, or to know who made the change.

On that note, if that user leaves the company, it does not sound like a good idea to delete him altogether, as there is information (like the log) still linked to this user. If we leave him in, however, and simply not display him, the admin might not know why a specific username is unavailable.

Also, if simply hiding deleted records is standard practice, does that not result to potentially huge tables with very rarely accessed data?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: some data should not be deleted, but marked as "inactive". i normally avoid deleting accounts, but deactivating them instead. also use constraints in your database to avoid non-consistent data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your question is NOT really a programming or for that matter a database design problem, it's more a business needs problem. moreover it is an open-ended question and therefore my reply may be subjective.

Just to mention the last point you ask about first,  "potentially" huge table is a relative statement. What are you keeping around for each individual ? Is it daily activity log for their entire employment history or is it nominal employee data?

For critical data, you can mark the data using a special status column (for instance you can mark someone as retired,fired etc. rather than deleting the record). You could also move the data to an archive table or even a separate archiving database with extra fields of archiving date etc.  There are many ways of dealing with the data.

Today's technology allows us to build databases that can house peta-bytes of data effectively.

Look at your organizational needs and use THAT as the criteria rather than thinking that a) it's a design issue, or b) that it is a programming problem.

Comment: You have a point Ahmed. The business decision HAS been made and I'm looking for how to implement it. The user example was the easiest I have come across. Other examples include deleting a record from any table and keeping a record that someone deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

In many projects I don't delete record, but marks them as deleted setting to true a field I created for every table.
So for example I use

```
UPDATE my_table SET deleted = true
WHERE id = ...
```

Remember that when you query valid records you have to specify

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE deleted = false
```

Comment: +1 For deleted=true. Macro it seems very good approach. But what If having millions of records and always coming new, new and new records? Do you not think that it can overload database?

Comment: Well, maybe. Putting an index on deleted field helps you anyway. Consider this: if you need to mantain records there are not many quick alternatives ;)

Comment: @AwaisQarni: look at my previous comment; I forgot to notify you, sorry

Comment: @Marco: It sounds like the most feasible idea. The problem arises that some things like username will not be able to be reused (and should they if they're linked?). I suppose it's the trade-off I need to make.

Comment: @TheoScholiadis: yes, I think this is what we have to pay to have this feature...

Answer (score 0):

If there's no further use and you can't think of any future for keeping the record in the database then go ahead and do a hard delete to keep the size of the table in check. In your case this is not the case, you should decide you need to keep the log or the log should be saved, ie whether to do a cascading delete or delete the user only and have the log remain as an orphan in the database.

As mentioned above adding a boolean column the table is a good idea. Another approach could be to use second database and move all records which are deleted from the original database to a secondary database.

As for standard practice I don't think there is any, you need to find a practice which fits to your need and implementation.

Comment: The second database is a good idea, but maybe impractical, as some of the data will still need to appear in the current/live database. E.g. you delete a user, but any updates he has made must still remain active. It's something to think about though...